# How to setup loadEagerly with tern-js?

Tags: plugin-ternjs

I am using the [ternjs for vim plugin](https://github.com/ternjs/tern_for_vim)  (based on [tern js project](http://ternjs.net/)) and standard vim omni-completion.
I am unable to get basic eager loading working with tern or I am misunderstanding how the `loadEagerly` option is supposed to work.
Here is my setup of files:

```
% tree -a 
.
├── index.html
├── index.js
├── lib.js
├── Session.vim
└── .tern-project
```

file: `index.html`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test tern</title>

</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello world</p>
    <script src="lib.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

file: `lib.js`

```
var namespace = {
    fruits : ['apple', 'bannana', 'orange'],
        text : "A tremor in the Force. The last time I felt it was in the presence of my old master."
};

function go(compare_me) {
    return compare_me === "reference";
}
```

file: `.tern-project`

```
{
    "libs": [
        "ecma5",
        "browser"
    ],
    "loadEagerly": ["*.js"],
    "plugins": {
        "node": {}
    }
}
```

tern itself is working, e.g. if I am in `lib.js` and type:
g<kbd>Ctrl-x</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-o</kbd>
 `go (fn)` appears in autocompletion dropdown list and a function signature appears in the preview window:

```
fn(compare_me: ?) -> bool
```

Now when I open `index.js` I am expecting "loadEagerly" to cause variables and functions from `lib.js` to appear in completion.
But its not - autocompletion is unresponsive, why?

Comment: Have you tried to  use ternjs directly? Then you could understand if the problem is with ternjs or the Vim plugin. You could also you try [the issue tracker](https://github.com/ternjs/tern_for_vim/search?q=loadEagerly&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93)?

Comment: @mMontu I didn't know it was possible to use ternjs directly but good idea, I will take a look. From what I have read in the issue threads loadEagerly works - and people have since moved on to discussions like *how do I get `**/*` patterns to work with loadEagerly or sometimes pattern A works but sometimes I need pattern B etc... But noone has seemed to raise the issue that `loadEagerly` is totally broken. But maybe for vim it is...?

Comment: Probably this Vim plugin just provide an easier interface for the ternjs, so the `loadEagerly` is probably just transferred by the plugin. There are [more issues on ternjs about the `loadEagerly`](https://github.com/ternjs/tern/search?q=loadEagerly&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93) than in the plugin.